# How to Fix Flutter Warning: Your Flutter application is created using an older version

Tags: flutter

I am receiving the following warning on running a Flutter App. Kindly guide how to fix it

```
Warning: Your Flutter application is created using an older version of the Android
embedding. It's being deprecated in favor of Android embedding v2.
```

Comment: I started to get same warning today and tried to apply https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects those steps and looks like worked so far.

Comment: Here is my answer, that worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70095530/7923782

Answer (score 108, accepted):

If you are here because of the flutter 2.10, do this:

Change this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="PassesBox"
    ...
```

To this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:label="PassesBox"
    ...
```

Answer (score 81):

You can add this to `AndroidManifest.xml` under `activity` tag.

```
<meta-data
         android:name="flutterEmbedding"
         android:value="2" />
```

This should remove the warning.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I got this error when added it: MainActivity.java:19: error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to FlutterEngine
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

Comment: Can you please explain the code?
Also, do we have to remove the older <meta-data> entry?

Comment: Yes, you can remove the older meta-data entry if you are using the post 1.12 flutter version. With this code, the flutter engine uses the latest version2 embedding. More details can be found here. `https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects#full-flutter-app-migration`

Comment: Should remove android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" from AndroidManifest.xml at <application> tag

Comment: Did not work for me...

Answer (score 22):

open your AndroidManifest.xml
just remove this line

```
android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 15):

**If you haven't added any native-specific code to your iOS/android folder:**

Delete the android and iOS files.

Then run `flutter create .` to fix the issue.

The command will recreate your Android and iOS file.

Comment: That'd would make you lose your code... Bad idea

Comment: if you haven't added any platform-specific code this can work.  Otherwise, you must copy methods, key properties and any files that you have added to your android folder. The same must be done to the ios folder too.  
Alternatively, you can follow https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects this link.

Answer (score 4):

Easy as pie... just Do this... Always works.
Change this in the AndroidMenifest.xml

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="PassesBox"
    ...
```

To this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:label="PassesBox"
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Just change this line:

```
io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity
```

with this:

```
io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
```

in AndroidManifest

For more details check this url https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

Answer (score 2):

(The following API 28 can be replaced with 29 as well since it is the latest as of now. 28 is recommended)

Change your target SDK and compile SDK version to 28

Install API 28 from File -> Settings -> Appearance and Behaviour -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK tools -> Select "Show package details from bottom right. Select all 28 versions, Apply.

Go to File -> Project Structure -> SDK's under Platform Settings -> Define Android API 28 as build target and enter the path for the SDK "C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk", Apply

Now, Go to modules under project settings in the same project structure, select Android API 28 from the dropdown. Restart the App.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make 2 changes in AndroidManifest.xml

First change this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="PassesBox"
    ...
```

To this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"
    android:label="PassesBox"
    ...
```

And second change

Add this under activity tag

```
<meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />
```

Answer (score 2):

2022 solution, first fully documented solution is [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects)

1 - remove main activity (if nothing custom is there)

2 - change name property in you mani fest to this             android:name="${applicationName}"

[image]

3 - add meta tag
under application tag(like what you see in picture)

```
<meta-data
android:name="flutterEmbedding"
android:value="2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to copy all the files you work with, mostly any assets folders, the lib folder and your pubsec.yaml file into a separate folder.

Then, trash your project folder and create a new one.

Copy/replace the old files over and re-run it.

Answer (score 1):

so sample
create a new flutter project
Click to File/New/New Flutter Project;
then run it to make sure anything is perfect.

copy all code from the old project and past it in New which is created.
make sure the Yamal file is also if you had changed on Yamal's.
and more all the essential files copy and past it on a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new flutter project and copy your source files over onto it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I opened a project on a laptop, but created it on a pc. I went to `android/app/src/build.gradle` and checked the `targetSdkVersion`, on my project is 29. After I opened Android Studio, I clicked on the SDK Manager icon and checked which SDK version I have on my laptop, 30. So I installed 29 SDK version. I restarted Visual Studio Code and I tried "pub get" again and got no errors.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
<applicationandroid:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" > <!-- code omitted --></application>
```

to this

```
<applicationandroid:name="${applicationName}"><!-- code omitted -->`enter code here`</application>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

first add this to AndroidManifest.xml under activity tag.

```xml
 <meta-data
    android:name="flutterEmbedding"
    android:value="2" 
/>
```

Then change this on AndroidManifest.xml under Application tag

```xml
android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
```

To this

```xml
android:name="${applicationName}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem running a test code as part of udemy course from GitHub repo [dicee-flutter](https://github.com/londonappbrewery/dicee-flutter)

As you can see, my flutter version is 3.16.9

```
flutter --version
Flutter 3.16.9 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
```

And my dart version is 3.2.6

```
  dart --version
Dart SDK version: 3.2.6 (stable) (Wed Jan 24 13:41:58 2024 +0000) on "macos_x64"
```

Straight away, you need below lines in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
```

There are quite a few extra changes I had to do, which are well documented in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects
So, follow it and find which one is troubling your use case.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same error, but after creating a new flutter project and copying and pasting both ios and android into my running project, it worked perfectly.