# The plugin `hexcolor` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding

Tags: flutter, pubspec

The plugin [`hexcolor`](https://pub.dev/packages/hexcolor) uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it, since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are the plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter

Can someone solve this, please???????

[image]

> pubspec.yamal

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  hexcolor: ^1.0.6
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64425132/10157127) may help

Answer (score 0):

Rather than this try using hexcolor: ^2.0.5 that is the latest stable version and if that doesn't work then change the **AndroidManifest.xml under activity tag**.

```
<meta-data
         android:name="flutterEmbedding"
         android:value="2" />
```

[image]