# flutter version created using an older version of the Android embedding

Tags: flutter, dart

How to make run for this project in the flutter
[image]
The Problem it shows me your flutter application is created an older version of the android embedding. so what should I do to solve problem please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Fix Flutter Warning: Your Flutter application is created using an older version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64425132/how-to-fix-flutter-warning-your-flutter-application-is-created-using-an-older-v)

Answer (score 0):

delete android folder of project and run following cmd

```
flutter create .
```

Comment: give me another solution

Comment: then goto the link and follow migration steps