# How can I solve the version of the Android embedding?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have this problem. Plz let me know how to solve this problem..
I got this git code from a lesson made about 2years ago.
Also different errors showed up when I made a flutter project using git code.

-> This is the problem
This app is using a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to migrate this app to the V2 embedding.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Your Flutter application is created using an older version of the Android embedding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65018588/your-flutter-application-is-created-using-an-older-version-of-the-android-embedd)

Answer (score 9):

If you are here because of the flutter 2.10, do this:

Change this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="PassesBox"
    ...
```

To this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:label="PassesBox"
    ...
```

Comment: Where is it located?

Comment: In the android/app/src/main/AndroidMnifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

If the application is very old, you should consult the migration guide that the documentation or fial offers you, just like the other answers recommend.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

but if you still have the deprecated application warnning try the following

- step one: delete the cache. `flutter clean`
- step two: remove the pubspec.lock file from the root of the project. `rm pubspec.lock`
- step three: update the libraries if you have any very outdated, you can do it manually or through the command. `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions` (this command will update all the libraries you have, be careful, before evaluating if such an update is necessary in your project).

then you must make some changes at the android folder level

- change the gradle.zip in `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to a newer version like:

  ```
  distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
  ```
- and in `android/build.gradle` update the version to

  ```
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
  ```
- the kotlin version in : `ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'`

and if you were using code obfuscation with `proguard-rules.pro`
remove any added configurations that reference that file in `android/app/build.gradle` and you should be left with just this

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
       
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release

     }
   }
```

finally close the code editor or the IDE you use
and in console run `flutter pub get` and run your project `flutter run`

Last but not least, do not forget to update the build version of your application to API 33 or higher and have your android studio updated (VERY IMPORTANT FOR UPDATE, )
[android-studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases)

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered before here on SO.

Here:
[Your Flutter application is created using an older version of the Android embedding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65018588/your-flutter-application-is-created-using-an-older-version-of-the-android-embedd)

And here: [How to Fix Flutter Warning: Your Flutter application is created using an older version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64425132/how-to-fix-flutter-warning-your-flutter-application-is-created-using-an-older-v)

You can also look at the source of how to migrate here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

Answer (score 0):

step 1: In android studio go to "android/app/src/main/java/[your/package/name]/MainActivity.java" and remove everything **except package at the top** paste the following as it is

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

}
```

step 2: Open "android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", under `<application` change

```
android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
```

to

```
android:name="${applicationName}"
```

Remove all `<meta-data>` tags with key `android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"` and paste

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
    android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
```

at its place
step 3: Add the following below the end of application tag i.e. below `</application>`

```
<meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
```

step 4: In terminal run `flutter clean`

Answer (score 0):

you should to add a config in your manifest:

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
```

Add a new  tag under .
and change name in manifest like this :
`android:name="${applicationName}"`