# Dart Flutter FlatButton not recognized and deprecated android embedding issue

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio

Hey I am new to flutter and dart i need help
please tell me why this "FlatButton" is not working.

```
 return Center(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: FlatButton(
              child: Image.asset('images/dice1.png'),
            ),
          ),
```

Even though the code was running fine before, i was still getting this red lines of error saying

"This app is using a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to migrate this app to the V2 embedding."

how can i fix this

I cannot understand why this is not working in my code. im always getting red underline even after updating the dependencies and the .yaml file to access images folder.

Comment: the embedding issue should be resolved once you follow this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75550548/18645340